# asp.net dynamic controls wierd values issue

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, controls

In my sample asp.net app, that can be found [here](http://www.away.co.za/DynControls1.rar) , I create dynamic controls on Page Init.
Then if the user enters text in the controls and the button is clicked, all the controls should be recreated with new values.

The page overwrites the populated values in the first row with the user's manually entered data.

Any ideas on how to prevent this without changing to html controls or MVC ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a workaround to keep state myself where I add a querystring variable to tell my code if its first load or postback. The I redirected to the same page with the new variable which forced the controls to be cleared.

Another way would have been to check IsPostBack on form load and replaced the ViewState assigned values again from my stored object values.

Still cant see why by disabling Viewstate on page and controls it still populates my dynamic controls with viewstate values.

Answer (score 0):

The viewstate is not available in the Page_Init Event.  Move the creation to the Page_Load event.

Comment: I dont want to use the viewstate(tried disabling it everywhere) and page_Load is too late in the Page lifecycle to add dynamic controls so that they persist after postback. Sometimes the controls are used as is, but sometimes they are refreshed so this problem is when the controls are supposed to be refreshed as per the sample app.

Comment: I understand where your coming from not wanting to use the veiwstate, however if you want the values in the control to persist you will have to use viewstate, or set the values yourself manually when the postback control.

Comment: I keeping state in the backend so no need for viewstate. The problem here is I cant find a way to get the page to ignore the viewstate/controlstate to not overwrite values that came from the backend state system. Thus far I only managed to get it to work with a Response.Redirect to the same page where I had to add a querystring var to tell my code I did a postback......big hack.

Comment: Can you use different id's of the textbox's between the page_init and the postback?